# How to parse XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a XML that has a structure similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompanyName>
    <AttrContainer>
        <Attr type="String">
            <Name value="'Name'" />
            <Value value="'AttrContainer'" />
        </Attr>
        <SubContainer>
            <AttrContainer value="'WSSMetadata'" />
            <AttrContainer>
                <Attr type="String">
                    <Name value="'Name'" />
                    <Value value="'AttrContainer'" />
                </Attr>
                <SubContainer>
                    <WSSMetadata value="'afe2e194-0ce7-4bfc-b446-9623e4fe7189'" />
                    <AttrContainer>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'Name'" />
                            <Value value="'WSSMetadata'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="Uuid">
                            <Name value="'scanID'" />
                            <Value value="afe2e194-0ce7-4bfc-b446-9623e4fe7189" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePath'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePathHD'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePathThumbnail'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePathGrey'" />
                            <Value value="'Images/afe2e194-0ce7-4bfc-b446-9623e4fe7189_grey.jpg'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePathGreyHD'" />
                            <Value value="'Images/afe2e194-0ce7-4bfc-b446-9623e4fe7189_grey_hd.jpg'" />
                        </Attr>
                        <Attr type="String">
                            <Name value="'imagePathGreyThumbnail'" />
                            <Value value="'Images/afe2e194-0ce7-4bfc-b446-9623e4fe7189_grey_thumbnail.jpg'" />
                        </Attr>
                    </AttrContainer>
                </SubContainer>
            </AttrContainer>
        </SubContainer>
    </AttrContainer>
</CompanyName>
```

and I am trying to parse it using this code (Linq to XML)

```
 var xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(filePathName);
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
 var attr = doc.Root.Elements("CompanyName");
 var x = attr.ToList();
```

but it `x` has no element.

#### My questions:

1. What is wrong with this code that I am not able to get the `CompanyName` element?
2. How can I get list of all `<SubContainer>` elements?
3. When I got the list of `<SubContainer>` elements, how can I read read and change its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is wrong with this code that I am not able to get the companyname element?**

The root element of your xml is `CompanyName`. So what your code is doing, it's essentially asking 'give me all `CompanyName` elements that are children of my root `CompanyName` element'. Hence the list is empty.

**how can I get list of all `SubContainer` elements.**

You can use

```
var subContainers = doc.Root.Descendants("SubContainer");
```

**when I got the list of `SubContainer` elements, how can I read read and change its content?**

```
foreach (var subContainer in subContainers)
{
   foreach (var attrContainer in subContainer.Elements("AttrContainer"))
   {
      var attr = attrContainer.Elements("Attr").FirstOrDefault();
      if (attr != null)
      {
         var oldValue = attr.Attribute("type").Value;
         attr.Attribute("type").Value = "something completely different";
      }
   }
}
```

This reads and changes the type on each first `Attr` element (assuming one exists) in all `AttrContainers` in all `SubContainers` - hopefully you can derive something meaningful out of that.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edited question as by some reason part of my question was not shown.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this instead:

```
var attr = doc.Root.Elements("AttrContainer");
```

`.Elements` returns child elements of that name.  `CompanyName` is you root node, and you're trying to search for its children which are `AttrContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

`doc.Root` returns the element `<CompanyName>`, so further selecting elements named `CompanyName` won't return any elements. You're effectively trying to select all `<CompanyName>` elements that are children of `<CompanyName>`.

This code will select all `<SubContainer>` elements no matter their depth. I'm suggesting this because your example XML has several `<SubContainer>` elements.

```
// Read all Attr elements
IEnumerable<XElement> subContainerElements = doc.Root.Descendants("SubContainer");

foreach (XElement subContainerElement in subContainerElements)
{
    // Work with <SubContainer> element here
}
```